# Swift dynamic view based on cell tapped in previous table view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view with a list of events. I now am trying to create a dynamic view that can show details about all of those events based on the event tapped on. Two questions I have are how do I create a generic segue that I can use for any table cell to go to the same view, and then in that view how do I access the cell that brought the user to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. First, create a variable `eventToPass` of type `Event` (or whatever your class is called) on your `ViewController`.  Then, you should get the object that represents your data, then pass that to your new `UIViewController`.  Something like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let event = eventsArray[indexPath.row]
    self.eventToPass = event

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EventSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "EventSegue") {
    var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as EventDetailViewController
        detailVC.event = eventToPass 
    }
}
```

This assumes that you have a `ViewController` called `EventDetailViewController` that has a property called `event`.  From here, you can access any of the `event`'s details on your new `ViewController`.

Comment: and then on the new view how would access the event? is that where you set detailVC.event so the variable would be accessed as `event`?

Comment: @MichaelStClair Yep, just edited my answer to make it more clear.  I also assumed the segue is called 'EventSegue'

Comment: Sorry, one last thing, how do I add the event property to the new view controller?

Comment: At the top of the new UIViewController, add `var event : Event! = nil` (or whatever class your object is.  I'm assuming you've created a class called `Event` that can hold the event information)

Comment: I believe this `detailVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("EventSegue", sender: self)` should be `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EventSegue", sender: self)`, I've got the segue working but I'm not getting the event to pass through

Comment: @MichaelStClair Hmm, try saving the selected event to a variable on your main ViewController, then override performSegue.  I've edited my answer